# How to implement csrf with subdomains in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, security, cors, csrf

```
const csrfProtection = csrf({ 
    cookie: { 
      domain: '.' + config_web.domain,
      secure: true,
      httpOnly: true,
      //sameSite: 'none'
    }, 
});

app.use(expresssession({
   store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
   secret: 'keyboard cat',
   resave: false,
   saveUninitialized: false,
   cookie: { 
     domain: '.' + config_web.domain, 
     maxAge: parseInt(cookiesTime), 
     secure: true, 
     httpOnly: true 
   }
}));

const corsOptions = {
  origin: ['https://api.domain.com', 'https://main.domain.com'],
  methods: 'POST',
  credentials: true,
  allowedHeaders: '*',//['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'X-Requested-With'],
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

I have the main site https://main.domain.com and will call api via https://api.domain.com.
After separating two subdomains, the api call is always fail from csrf. I wonder if any cookie stuff I set incorrectly?

Comment: and the value of config_web.domain is? I mean what does it look like? I'm guessing domin.com?

Answer (score -2):

```
$.ajax({
   url: a_cross_domain_url,
   xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
   }
});
```

just found add xhrFields in frontend side then works